# PDF Reader Lib for Android

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-reader

i need to find a library that allow me to open pdfs on android. This have to happen in a view inside my application and this lib cannot be GPL (i'm fine with LGPL) or licensed (the ones i saw was way to damn expensive for me).

I found [pdf-renderer](http://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer) that is LGPL but i can't find a way to open pdfs, only to create them (a thing that i don't need atm).

Cheers

Comment: Did you find one? I am also looking for something similar - lgpl, I found andpdf to be extremely slow

Comment: Hey. Did you find one? Only found that it is either GPL or need to buy license. andpdf can be acceptable but it cannot show chinese characters.

Answer (score 0):

how is your research so far?

have you checked http://sourceforge.net/projects/andpdf/

it is LGPL